# MPLAB X IDE 6.15 Assembly Toolchain

Tags: assembly, pic, microchip, mplab

Years ago I worked with MPLAB and have decided to start learning it again for an upcoming project.  For the PIC microcontroller's I prefer to work in assembly, however I am have issues setting it up.

I installed MPLAB X IDE 6.15 and read that it doesn't come with any toolchains pre-installed and I am trying to figure out how to install the assembly toolchain.  I downloaded a version of mpasm (from Microchip's website), however it doesn't work.  If I select the folder from Tools --> Options --> Embedded --> Build Tools it says it can't find the builder.  Also, if I try to run the executable in the mpasm folder it says it can't run on my OS (Windows 10).  Reviewing the MPLAB documentation though suggests that it should still support assembly programming.  Unfortunately, any tutorials I found were for older versions of MPLAB (i.e., 5.x and before).

Can anyone confirm if MPLAB X IDE 6.15 actually still supports assembly?  If so, is there any installer and/or documentation you can point me to about getting the toolchain setup in this version so I can write/build/deploy assembly projects?  TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, MPLABX dropped MPASM compiler as of version 5.40 but now provides a new assembly compiler which comes with a related XC compiler tool chains. Since microchip manifactures 8, 16 and 32 bit microcontrollers, the toolchains are named XC8 for 8-bit, XC16 for 16-bit and XC32 for 32-bit controllers.
However new assembly syntax is slightly different from the former one.

So you have 2 options...

1. Download and install the [XC8 Compiler](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/tools-resources/develop/mplab-xc-compilers/downloads-documentation#XC8) which comes with the new assembley compiler named **pic-as** and learn new syntax by referring to the [MPLAB® XC8 PIC® Assembler User's Guide](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/DEV/ProductDocuments/UserGuides/MPLAB-XC8-PIC-Assembler-User-Guide-50002974.pdf).
2. If you want to code in older fashion of assembly you can still use MPLABX with 3rd party toolchains like [GNU PIC Utilities](https://gputils.sourceforge.io). The preferred way to integrate this toolchain into the MPLABX IDE is to select
   **Tools -> Plugins** from the menu, then select and install it. See the plugins window image below.

[image: MPLABX plugins window]

Comment: Thank you very much.  I have always found Microchips documentation regarding MPLAB to be severely lacking/hard to find.  This should get me going.